Simulating the breakdown of a machine during its use in Anylogic
I currently model a process where I use machines that break down with a certain distrubution. Now I noticed that my logic is kind of off since the breakdown can happen before the machine is even in use. I modelled it using an event that sets a parameter of wether the machine is working on true or false. Is there a way of limiting the occurance / resetting of the breakdown event of the machine to only the time the machine is working?
Any type of help would be apprechiated!




Tons of ways, this is just 1 option:
Use a state chart inside the machine agent type with 2 states: working & idle. Trigger changes between them according to your work/idle logic.
Add a third state broken that can only be reached from working state. Set it up with a timeout transition (or similar) that only counts down when inside the working state.
The details depend on your model but this may be a good starting point.

Thank you! I have actually tried this before, but I am struggeling with accessing the current state of the machine in the Main. How do I best do that? I tried the following 1) Define a variable in the Machines Agent that is set everytime the state changes. But I can somehow not access it in the Main 2) I tried accessing the state with isStateActive() directly what also doesn't work - Do you see where I went wrong? I added the pictures (I just do go very simple in the beginning)

pls always open new questions for separate issues, SOF is not a forum but a Q&A place. Helps future users to find this if they have similar issues (and you can use the search here as others had this same problem as well... but feel free to open a new issue anytime :) ). Some tips: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow
